# C# - Sending Notifications with Firebase returns error 500

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a notification from my server (C#) to Firebase. But it seems that Firebase keeps returning:

```
 System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

I have, after going over the simple code, I tried to test it on Postman (*Chrome extension*):

Request:

```
POST
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

headers: 
Authorization: key=1:********:android:90d906ac519686d0 (i got this from the firebase console under App id in project settings)

Content-Type: application/json

Sender: id=******office-906 (i got this from firebase console under ProjectId)

body:
{ "to" : "dlDtgNcjWXQ:APA91bHTJdgfrOG345EAz0muNdgoxoDEJ_LUKCIK61R1esPLAyLemPRrV0sTcve3RG20FNvs8pt....U81uRZ9WZ32EtXL2wH0hXSruOddz"
}
```

Response:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Internal Server Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
    <H1>Internal Server Error</H1>
    <H2>Error 500</H2>
</BODY>
```

So if I ignore C# for a second, it seems I get the same error from Postman as well. What am I doing wrong? I read the guides and documentations. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you sending for the `notification` data? [See documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications) for a description of the contents and an example.

Comment: the most minimal posible according to the docs: { "to" : "dlDtgNcjWXQ:APA91bHTJdgfrOG345EAz0muNdgoxoDEJ_LUKCIK61R1esPLAyLemPRrV0sTcve3RG20FNvs8pt....U81uRZ9WZ32EtXL2wH0hXSruOddz" }

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-http-connection-server-protocol
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

`Authorization: key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY`

Make sure that `YOUR_SERVER_KEY` is the server key, whose value is visible in your Firebase Project Console under <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> > *Cloud Messaging* Tab

You seem to be using the app id `(1:********:android:90d906ac519686d0)`. Also, the Sender header is not required or documented.

Comment: I ran a test that confirms this answer.  I sent a valid message using curl and then replaced the valid server key with the (incorrect) App ID key. With the App ID key, I got the same Internal Server Error response reported in the OP.